# iOS: How to scroll navigation bar as view controller scrolls

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to scroll the navigation bar as the user scrolls on the view controller. This should be similar to how the YouTube app's home page is working. When the user scrolls down, the navigation bar should be made visible. The navigation bar should move as much as the scroll amount.

I'm aware of `hidesBarOnSwipe` and `setNavigationBarHidden`, but these do not give precise control of the y-axis. I'm also reading that Apple does not support directly modifying the navigation bar frame.

So, how does YouTube do this? I'm looking for an MVP demonstrating navigation bar position change along with a `UIScrollView` offset change.

Comment: maybe this link helps you:https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView

Comment: Please don't post *"similar to how [some other app] is doing this"*. Take the time to describe what you want to do, and show what you've done so far in trying to accomplish it. Review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Without additional detail about what you want to do, I'll make some guesses.

First, the top of the YouTube app's home page is almost certainly ***not*** a `UINavigationBar` -- it doesn't behave like one, there is no pushing/popping of controllers going on, it's in a tab bar controller setup, etc.

So, let's assume it's a view with subviews - we'll call it a "sliding header view" - and your goal is:

- don't let the header view's top scroll down
- "push it up" when scrolling up
- "pull it down" when scrolling down

We can accomplish this by constraining the Top of that header view to the Top of the scroll view's Frame Layout Guide.

- when we *start* to scroll, we'll save the current `.contentOffset.y`
- when we scroll, we'll get the relative scroll y distance
- if we're scrolling Up, we'll change the Top Constraint `.constant` value to move the header view up
- if we're scrolling Down, we'll change the Top Constraint `.constant` value to move the header view down

Here's how it will look at the start:

[image]

as we scroll up just a little:

[image]

after we've scrolled up farther:

[image]

as we scroll down just a little:

[image]

after we've scrolled down farther:

[image]

Here's the example code for that:

**Simple two-label "header" view**

```
class SlidingHeaderView: UIView {
    
    // simple view with two labels
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        let v1 = UILabel()
        v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v1.text = "Label 1"
        v1.backgroundColor = .yellow
        addSubview(v1)

        let v2 = UILabel()
        v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v2.text = "Label 2"
        v2.backgroundColor = .yellow
        addSubview(v2)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            v1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            v1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            v2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            v2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            
            v1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            v2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            v2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            
            v2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.heightAnchor),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

**example view controller**

```
class SlidingHeaderViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        return v
    }()
    let slidingHeaderView: SlidingHeaderView = {
        let v = SlidingHeaderView()
        return v
    }()
    let contentView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        return v
    }()

    // Top constraint for the slidingHeaderView
    var slidingViewTopC: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // to track the scroll activity
    var curScrollY: CGFloat = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        [scrollView, slidingHeaderView, contentView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        // add contentView and slidingHeaderView to the scroll view
        [contentView, slidingHeaderView].forEach { v in
            scrollView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        // add scroll view to self.view
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        // we're going to change slidingHeaderView's Top constraint relative to the Top of the scroll view FRAME
        slidingViewTopC = slidingHeaderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // scroll view Top to view Top
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // scroll view Leading/Trailing/Bottom to safe area
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain slidingHeaderView Top to scroll view's FRAME
            slidingViewTopC,
            
            // slidingHeaderView to Leading/Trailing of scroll view FRAME
            slidingHeaderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            slidingHeaderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // no Height or Bottom constraint for slidingHeaderView
            
            // content view Top/Leading/Trailing/Bottom to scroll view's CONTENT GUIDE
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // content view Width to scroll view's FRAME
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
        // add some content to the content view so we have something to scroll
        addSomeContent()
        
        // because we're going to track the scroll offset
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if slidingHeaderView.frame.height == 0 {
            // get the size of the slidingHeaderView
            let sz = slidingHeaderView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude), withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow)
            // use its Height for the scroll view's Top contentInset
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: sz.height, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
    }
    
    func addSomeContent() {
        // create a vertical stack view with a bunch of labels
        //  and add it to our content view so we have something to scroll
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 32
        stack.backgroundColor = .gray
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        for i in 1...20 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.text = "Label \(i)"
            v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48.0).isActive = true
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        contentView.addSubview(stack)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0),
        ])
    }
    
}

extension SlidingHeaderViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        curScrollY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let diffY = scrollView.contentOffset.y - curScrollY
        var newY: CGFloat = slidingViewTopC.constant - diffY
        if diffY < 0 {
            // we're scrolling DOWN
            newY = min(newY, 0.0)
        } else {
            // we're scrolling UP
            if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -slidingHeaderView.frame.height {
                newY = 0.0
            } else {
                newY = max(-slidingHeaderView.frame.height, newY)
            }
        }
        // update slidingHeaderView Top constraint constant
        slidingViewTopC.constant = newY
        curScrollY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }
    
}
```

Everything is done via code - no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections needed.